# Repeating a formula in a column in Google Docs

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, google-docs

I have struggled for a long time with this.  I need to enter the same formula in every cell of a column.  However it changes the formula as it is dragged or copied.  e.g. =J2 becomes =J3 =J4 etc.  I need just =J2 in every cell.

Answer (score 2):

Try `=$J$2` instead of `=J2`

The $ symbol keeps the reference as-is, that is does not change it when it is dragged.

HTH.